# Get unique data from multiple tables week by week

Tags: php, mysql, join, union, multiple-tables

I have a hard time dealing with multiple tables. I want to get the total number of products from all orders placed week by week.
I used the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT  id_order, order_placed FROM orders                      
        WHERE YEAR(order_placed) = YEAR(NOW()) 
        AND WEEKOFYEAR(order_placed) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())";
```

The above query will return all orders placed the current week. Then I added a new sql query to get all the product IDs from the retrieved ID orders.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT id_product, COUNT(id_product) AS num_products 
         FROM order_product 
         WHERE id_order = '".$id_order."'";
$results2 = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql2);
```

In the same way I get the rest info. When I print the final statement it will be like:

```
Order ID: 1, Date: 06/07/2015, Product: 100052, Name: Example A
Order ID: 1, Date: 06/07/2015, Product: 100052, Name: Example A
Order ID: 2, Date: 07/07/2015, Product: 9987,   Name: Example B
```

But I want to find a way to show the total number:

```
Order ID: 1, Date: 06/07/2015, Product: 100052, Name: Example A, Count: 2
Order ID: 2, Date: 07/07/2015, Product: 9987,   Name: Example B, Count: 1
```

Also I will group them by week so each line will contain just info from the current week.

Below you can see the tables to get an idea (I simplify them a lot in order to be easier for you)

ORDERS

```
-----------------------------------
| Order ID |  Date                 |
-----------------------------------
| 1        |  06/07/2015 15:20:01  |
-----------------------------------
| 2        |  07/07/2015 10:10:41  |
-----------------------------------
```

ORDER_PRODUCTS

```
    ------------------------------------------
    | Order ID |  Product ID  | Product Type |
    ------------------------------------------
    | 1        |  10052       |  1           |
    ------------------------------------------
    | 1        |  10052       |  1           |
    ------------------------------------------
    | 2        |  9987        |  0           |
    ------------------------------------------
```

A customer can order as many products as he wants.. That is why the above table contain 10052 ID twice. That customer for example ordered 10052 twice.
Also, I only want type '1' to be retrieved.

PRODUCT_ID_NAME

```
------------------------
| Product ID | ID Name |
------------------------
| 10052      |  1      |
------------------------
| 9987       |  2      |
------------------------
```

PRODUCT NAME

```
--------------------------
| ID Name | Product Name |
--------------------------
| 1       |  Example_A   |
--------------------------
| 2       |  Example_B   |
--------------------------
```

Can anyone help me with this?
The goal is to display the number of products sold each week.

```
Week 1: Example A sold: 150, Example B sold: 15
Week 2: Example A sold: 100, Example B sold: 50
etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP_BY` is your friend here.

I'm not sure about your table or column names, but this should get you on your way:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.order_placed, op.product_id, pn.product_name, COUNT(op.order_id) AS `count` 
FROM `orders` o
INNER JOIN `order_products` op ON op.order_id = o.id
INNER JOIN `product_id_name` pin ON pin.product_id = op.product_id
INNER JOIN `product_name` pn ON pn.id_name = pin.id_name

WHERE YEAR(o.order_placed) = YEAR(NOW()) 
AND WEEKOFYEAR(o.order_placed) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY op.order_id
```

[edit] Ak, this will get you to

`Order ID: 1, Date: 06/07/2015, Product: 100052, Name: Example A, Count: 2
Order ID: 2, Date: 07/07/2015, Product: 9987,   Name: Example B, Count: 1`

I didn't see the bit about grouping them by product - but that's more of the same thing. Just group by the product ID rather than the Order ID.

Comment: I think this won't return the desired results. If let's say product "100" is ordered from different ID orders this week. For example order id 1, 3, 5, 7. So the count will be 4. Product "100" is sold 4 times. Then I will only need ONE LINE for the current week. Current week: 1, Product: 100, Count: 4

Comment: I saw that - so instead of grouping by the order ID, group by the product ID.

Comment: Ok thanks for that :) So instead of having multiple sql queries to get step by step all the variables... I should have one query with INNER JOINS etc to get it instantly. Will give it a try

Comment: Note that you'll need one query per week if you use the method above.

Comment: I understand. If I want to get the results of all weeks in 2015 I will just have the "WHERE YEAR(o.order_placed) = YEAR(NOW()) " and group them also by week_year. As well as add in select the "WEEKOFYEAR(order_placed) as week_year" or something similar to that. I think that should work. I need to test it. Thank you